# Can I embed Google Map directions into my own website?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are creating a website for motorbike tours and would like our visitors to be able to enter a start and end location and have this update an embedded Google map on our own website, basically highlighting the best route.  We'd like it to work exactly as the "Directions" feature on Google Maps works.

Is this possible?  If so, how best to acheive this?

Also, we'd like to restrict the businesses and places of interest that appear on the map as some of them simply won't be relevant to our motorcycle audience.  Is it possible to filter out businesses and places of interest and only display what we would like to display?

Really appreciate any advice that could be offered.  Thank you.

Regards
Nath.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can there is already a post with a HTML example. There are limitations on how many requests can be performed in 1 day for free usage.  Check the licensing information on the google site.

[google maps plot route between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848763/google-maps-plot-route-between-two-points)

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can.
Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/) (the first is for javascript functionality, the second for server-side functionality through web services).
With these API you can show map, show pinned point on that and, using the direction API, you can also calculate the best route among other things.

About the businesses and places you want to show, you can use the [places API](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/maps/documentation/places/). though I never used this one, so I can only suggest to have a look at the documetation.

Comment: Would have been good to directly quote the webpages linked because link is now broken.